# Rabbit Mq status check

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, rabbitmq

In my spring, hibernate application RMQ is used. I have a url in this application to check the status the DB connection and the status of the threads. I also want to include the status check of `RMQ` connection from the application. Please guide me.

Comment: @kzhen: thanks for your suggestions. I am still trying to find the best answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to give a specific answer as this depends on how you manage connections to the RabbitMQ broker in your application...

However in essence all you need to do is look at the IsOpen property on the connection

You probably have this code somewhere in your application:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.set...
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
```

all you need to do to check the current state is:

```
bool connected = connection.IsOpen();
```